# Understanding a parametric question

Tags: parametric, parametrization

The parametric form of a relation is given by: 
$$x = rsin\theta$$
$$y = rcos\theta$$
for $0≤ θ ≤ 2π$

Eliminate θ so as to find the relationship explicitly between $x$ and $y$.

What is this question asking me to do exactly? just write: $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$?

Comment: Yes, exactly, you do have the equation of a circle and the angle $\theta$ you can easily to see where is its position drawing a circle centered at the origin

Comment: Thanks Piquito, I'll try all that. Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome dear friend. Good Luck.